# Edit column with stylename

Tags: java, css, gwt

I have a celltable with some columns, and want make 2 of them hidden, I tried to make a celltable column hidden, while doing following with css stylename:

```
firstColumn.setCellStyleNames("hide");
```

css:

```
.hide{
 display:none;
}
```

but I get only the rows hidden, but not the header of the column, and the table not passed to the rest column, but there is still a white space on the column, I want to get hide all column with it header, how can I do it, any suggestion please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.setCellSomething` will have effect only on the inner rows, not on the header. For that, use `.setHeaderSomething`, so:

```
firstColumn.setHeaderStyleNames("hide");
```

[**Gwt Project Docs - setHeaderStyleNames**](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/Header.html#setHeaderStyleNames(java.lang.String))